# Why Javascript Sublevel menu is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone check the issue with my basic multilevel navigation. In my menu, when i click on "About" it working properly. But when i click on "Profile" under About menu, it is not working due to JS is assigning a "display:none" to it's sublevel menu. Can anyone explain me whats wrong with my code. I thinked on the perspective of even bubbling, but eventhough my code should work as per the order of Parent and child. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in Advance!

```js
let menus = document.querySelectorAll(".main-navigation ul li a");
menus.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.parentElement.querySelector("ul")) {
    item.parentElement.classList.add("has-submenu");
  }
});

let submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".has-submenu");
submenu.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let ul = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("ul");
    let cs = window.getComputedStyle(ul).display;
    if (cs === "none") {
      ul.style.cssText = "display:block";
    } else {
      ul.style.cssText = "display:none";
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  padding: .35rem;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.main-navigation ul li ul {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About +</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Profile +</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Management</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Mission</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Services +</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Web Development</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a solution, but I suggest you delegate the clicks to ".main-navigation" and sort out what is clicked in there.

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan to give me a thread to solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just because your event propagates(when has-submenu container is clicked) as the profile tab is within another submenu. Just try adding a console log inside the event listener. you could see it getting triggered twice. I have added a stopPropagation() method. This whole code can be improved a bit and I leave it to you. As @mplungjan suggested event delegation is the right way to do this.

```js
let menus = document.querySelectorAll(".main-navigation ul li a");
menus.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.parentElement.querySelector("ul")) {
    item.parentElement.classList.add("has-submenu");
  }
});

let mn = document.querySelector(".main-navigation");
mn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  <!-- alert("I'm main navigation and now i'm clicked"); -->
})

let submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".has-submenu");
submenu.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    let ul = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("ul");
    let cs = window.getComputedStyle(ul).display;
    if (cs === "none") {
      ul.style.cssText = "display:block";
    } else {
      ul.style.cssText = "display:none";
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  padding: .35rem;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.main-navigation ul li ul {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About +</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Profile +</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Management</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Mission</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Services +</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Web Development</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Vinu Prasad, Thank you for your initiation. I tried "console.log(e.target)" and i got "Profile" menu is doubling here. My question is, if bubbling happens here why the same element is doubling. As per my understandling when i click on "Profile" menu, it should console "Profile" and "About" menus in the perspective of bubbling. Hopes you understand my confusion. Can you explain on my concern.

Comment: @RenJitsm Assume you have opened the about nav. Now you try to click the profile tab. Event bubbles up(because the event handler is available for the about submenu as well), starting the event handler for the profile submenu. and then moves up to the about sub-menu. At this point, you are still referring to e.target(as it is which triggered the event) which still is the anchor tag representing the profile. Try printing out the currentTarget(e.currentTarget) here. The current target refers to the one to which the event handler is attached and it will show the about submenu the second time.

Comment: @VinuPrasad You agree that delegation is better, but why are you then not delegating from the container `main-navigation` ? You have a non-active event listener for `main-navigation`

Comment: @mplungjan I have shown him the right path pointed out his mistake and answered his subsequent query. I believe he got to learn something from it today rather than copy-pasting an answer and that is what really matters. Isn't that the right way to learn things? I will surely help him out if he tries and couldn't succeed with delegation.

Comment: @VinuPrasad you are right, when i use "e.currentTarget" i able to see the bubble of event. But why the sublevel of "Profile" gets "display:none". If bubble happens when i click on "Profile", it should be hide sublevel of "About" itself. Can you explain it.

Comment: @RenJitsm, same reason. when you click on to profile tab, e.target refers to the anchor tag inside profile right? and you are then doing -> e.target.parentElement.querySelector("ul") which in turn points to profile tab's child (e.target.parent returns the profile li and queryselector('ul') return the ul item inside it) which already were displayed block and now you toggle it to display none. Please debug it line by line and see what is returned at each line

Comment: @VinuPrasad, I tried to debug from my end as i can possible. But could'nt figure it out how JS consider the sublevel of "Profile" menu is "display:block" eventhough it is basically "display:none".  Thanks for answering my contineous queries. I eager to really understand how JS works here. Excuse me for it. You may also ignore questions if you get bored.